# Vscode induces strong network bandwidth?

Tags: visual-studio-code, networking, bandwidth, slowdown

I've installed VScode since a few days, and I was experiencing strong network slowdowns. I thought it was my provider, but I noticed that it was only occuring when VScode was opened...

Using a Network tool, I noticed a strong data sending from my computer to waws-prod-am2-325.cloudapp.net which seems to be a server from microsoft. And also 52.182.143.210 which is recognized as "Microsoft Azure"

What is the problem ?  How can I solve it ?

Note that I uninstalled any extension.

Comment: I just notice that it comes from the SYNC feature that was sending a lot of informations for days now... Is it normal ?  I did barely not customize VSCODE for the moment, so my config should be light to save on remote servers...

Comment: the logs of sync seems to report problems, but it's too big to be posted here...

example : 
[2022-10-27 10:41:45.895] [settingssync] [error] RequestFailed (UserDataSyncError) syncResource:unknown operationId:unknown: Connection refused for the request 'https://vscode-sync.trafficmanager.net/v1/resource/snippets'.